# When modelling my app can I reuse NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: ios

I think this is a common scenario. 
I'm defining class models of my app, I will use Core Data for caching so I would like to take advantage of the NSManagedObject generated subclass to "reuse" it as a model to pass to different classes.
Is that advisable?
Let's say I get some data from the network I want to build an object model with same instance variables as the Core Data model generated, use it when needed and maybe cache it on the DB.
What is the common approach there?
Can I use a category on Core Data model?
Core Data subclass? Encapsulation? New class ?
Thanks for any tips on that.

Comment: You should see mogenerator : http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/

Comment: Thanks, I expected some kind of pattern since I guess is something quite common in many apps.

Comment: I must admit that I did not fully understand your question and it might be beneficial to clarify it (take the time to expand it with a case scenario). Still, when you're interested in subclassing NSManagedObject and using Core Data in general, mogenerator is a tremendously useful tool.

Comment: I download a JSON that represent a certain Item. I use it in my views and also store in DB for future usage and caching.
So I was wondering why not reuse the Core Data generated managed object subclass, but I guess it is just for Core Data usage.
I just didn't want to write by hand a class with same attributes, and possibly not use a non SDK command line.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data is not, at its heart, a database, but rather an object graph manager.

In many scenarios, it is a very good idea to handle your objects with Core Data, and you can use a fast in-memory store.

In a way, I think that by attempting NOT to use Core Data to handle your objects, you are destined to re-implement a lot of its functionality. Just use it.

You say that you are downloading a JSON that represents a given item; and you're using this item in your views, and then persisting it in a database. Core Data *excels* at this; take advantage of its full set of features instead of trying to avoid it.

(And, again, using mogenerator will be very helpful, although it is certainly not required).

Matt Gallagher has a nice blog article about the differences between Core Data and a database - I suggest that you read it, it's valuable information.

[Cocoa With Love: The differences between Core Data and a Database](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html)

Comment: Thanks; I read that article some time ago. I Think mogenerator does what I need, my idea was to use NSManagedObject generated subclass as a model class for an object that may be stored on DB or not.